# Save only without load

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

There is a model, mapped to stored procedures for saving to DB by fluent API (i.e. by overriding `DbContext.OnModelCreating` and using `MapToStoredProcedures`).

I do not want to load this model, since I'm going to fill it from code.

So my `DbContext` should return empty data collection, but still track changes and save it by `SaveChanges()` call.

What should I write in `DbContext.OnModelCreating` to achieve this?